# Cannot import Observable.fromEvent - RXJS

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6

I'm trying to create an Observable from an input event. I have already tried almost everything and I can not import "fromEvent". This is my code. I am using angular 6.0.1 and RXJS 6.1.0

**error TS2339: Property 'fromEvent' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.**

```
import { Directive, EventEmitter, Input, Output, ElementRef, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/internal/operators/distinctUntilChanged';
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/internal/operators/debounceTime';
import { map } from 'rxjs/internal/operators/map';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/internal/operators/filter';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/Observable';
//import 'rxjs/internal/observable/fromEvent';
//import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';

@Directive({
  selector: '[ngModel][debounceTime]'
})
export class InputDebounceDirective implements AfterViewInit {

  @Output()
  public onDebounce = new EventEmitter<any>();

  @Input('debounceTime')
  public debounceTime: number = 1500;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private currentModel: NgControl) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    Observable.fromEvent(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'keyup')
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(this.debounceTime),
        distinctUntilChanged()
      )
      .subscribe(x => {
        this.onDebounce.emit(x);
      });

  }

}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You must import `fromEvent` as follows in RxJS6:

```
import {fromEvent} from 'rxjs';
```

Read the [migration guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md) for further information, in particular have a look on the [import paths](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#import-paths) section there.

When using `fromEvent` use it as a function as follows:

```
fromEvent(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'keyup')
```

Not as a static method as follows (this was correct in previous RxJS versions)

```
Observable.fromEvent(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'keyup')
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help, but the error persists :(

Comment: @avechuche Also, you shouldn't import nothing from `internal` (in any rxjs version). As V6, Import operators from `rxjs/operators`, e.g.: `import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators`.

Comment: @developer033 why you recommand that ? for me this help your bundler to not include death code. But i may not award from some restriction.