# How to fix ‘debounceTime & distinctUntilChanged | RxJS’ error in Angular 5 using typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an input search element that I detect keyup and I want to use debounce to limit request made to the API but I can't get it working. I'm just trying to test debounceTime and distinctUntilChanged.

I have already tried (Keyup) but can't get it working.

```
<input (keyup)="onKeyUp($event)"  id="testInput" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="searchFilterText" class="m-list-search__form-input" value="" placeholder="Search...">
```

Here is the code from the typescript file.

```
searchInput = document.getElementById('testInput');
observable: any;

/// <summary>
/// Process the search term provided on key up for the input field.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="searchTerm">The search term.</param>
onKeyUp(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    //console.log(event);
    let element = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    let value = element.value;

    this.observable = fromEvent(this.searchInput, event.type)
        .debounceTime(500) // millisecs until value gets emitted.
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .subscribe(function (event) {
            console.log(event.target.value);
        });
}
```

The expected result is a delayed search result value in the console log using debounceTime and distinctUntilChanged.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try this:

**Template**

```
<input  
       id="testInput" autocomplete="off"
       type="text" #searchText
       name="searchFilterText" class="m-list-search__form-input"
       value=""
       placeholder="Search...">
```

Notice the template reference variable: `#searchText`. This allows access to the input element without needing `getElementById` (which is not normally recommended to use in an Angular app).

**Component**

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
   templateUrl: './search.component.html'
})
export class SearchComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('searchText') searchTextRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.searchTextRef) {
      fromEvent(this.searchTextRef.nativeElement, 'keyup')
        .pipe(
            debounceTime(500),
            distinctUntilChanged()
        ).subscribe(
          value => console.log(this.searchTextRef.nativeElement.value)
        )
    }
  }
}
```

This code uses `@ViewChild` to get the reference to the element marked with the `#searchText` template reference variable.

It then uses code similar to what you had for the `debounceTime`.

I have a stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-debounce-deborahk

And you can find more info here:  [Observable.fromEvent - RXJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50355584/observable-fromevent-rxjs)

Note: This is even easier if you use **reactive forms** as you can directly access the `valueChanges` observable for any input element on a form.

**Reactive Forms**

**Template**

```
<input  
       id="testInput"
       [formControl]="search"
       autocomplete="off"
       type="text"
       class="m-list-search__form-input"
       value=""
       placeholder="Search...">
```

Notice the `formControl` directive.

**Component**

```
  // For reactive forms
  search = new FormControl();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.search.valueChanges
            .pipe(
          debounceTime(500),
          distinctUntilChanged()
        ).subscribe(
          value => console.log("Reactive Forms implementation: " + value)
        )
  }
```

Comment: this is great thanks. Do you have any ideas of how to include distinctUntilChanged() into the logic?

Comment: What would you expect `distinctUntilChanged` to do in this context?

Comment: If I type the word test then type test1 and then type test the last value change gets ignored right or have I got it wrong and it's not needed in my case.

Comment: Just add it within the `pipe`. i'll update my answer.

Comment: Hi, @DeborahK does order of distinctUntilChanged, debounceTime matter? i have noticed making distinctUntilChanged before debounceTime make network call each time even if value is same. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, order matters. Think of it as data going through a pipeline of operations in their defined order.